# Send email regardless php.ini settings

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, email

I have some real problems with my host, as they **didn't set up the php.ini for email sending** and now **my app would need to send emails with token code** and etc. I work with only few users and their email addresses are secured next to their login data.

**`sendmail_from` is empty** and just to give a better idea is that the **domain name in php.ini is not even the same as the actual domain name**.

I **have only MySQL and FTP access** parameters from them. Probably I can't access then php.ini, right? (I'm unsure as lack knowledge here, excuse me please)

*On localhost with XAMPP I can send emails easily as I can configure locally php.ini just as I like.*

**Is there a way to send emails** (probably not emailto couse that wouldn't be very nice) **at the press of a button, yet disregarding what php.ini contains as it seems I can't access php.ini?**

My app is mainly built on Javascript/JQuery. I use PHP mainly to hide out sensible information, to handle login sessions and cookies. I'm very new to PHP.

**Thank you in advance for any suggestion provided!**

Comment: ask your host for a refund. change host. profit.

Comment: Yes. Would be awesome, but let's say it's out of the question (also due to the fact they only work from monday and I wan't to do it this weekend without them!). I have accounts with other hosts as well but they provide such a complete service I never had to learn all this stuff. Made me lazy as well and now I have to make all this research and to autoeducate my lazy self.

Comment: I don't think having things work the way they're supposed to is lazy, I'm with @LozCherone on this one.

Comment: @Laci a predicament, how about you setup a simple API mail proxy script on a working host, then just curl the message from broken host to one of your other hosts and then on monday ask the host to fix the problem or you want a refund.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using something like [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer). According to their github:

> Used by many open-source projects: Drupal, SugarCRM, Yii, Joomla! and
>   many more

This is a mailer class which you can use instead of `mail()` - allowing you to configure it without changing your `php.ini`.

If sendmail is available to you, you can do something like the following:

```
<?php
require '../PHPMailerAutoload.php';

//Create a new PHPMailer instance
$mail = new PHPMailer();
// Set PHPMailer to use the sendmail transport
$mail->isSendmail();
//Set who the message is to be sent from
$mail->setFrom('from@example.com', 'First Last');
//Set an alternative reply-to address
$mail->addReplyTo('replyto@example.com', 'First Last');
//Set who the message is to be sent to
$mail->addAddress('whoto@example.com', 'John Doe');
//Set the subject line
$mail->Subject = 'PHPMailer sendmail test';
//Read an HTML message body from an external file, convert referenced images to embedded,
//convert HTML into a basic plain-text alternative body
$mail->msgHTML(file_get_contents('contents.html'), dirname(__FILE__));
//Replace the plain text body with one created manually
$mail->AltBody = 'This is a plain-text message body';
//Attach an image file
$mail->addAttachment('images/phpmailer_mini.png');

//send the message, check for errors
if (!$mail->send()) {
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo "Message sent!";
}
```

Otherwise you will require an SMTP server which you can use it with.

Comment: A gmail account can by used as the smtp server, with phpmailer

Comment: I get this: `2014-05-03 15:55:20 SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known (0) SMTP connect() failed. Message could not be sent.Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed.` . I'm trying Google SMTP

Comment: `$mail->isSMTP();  // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'smtp.google.com';  // Specify main and backup server
$mail->Port = 587;                                                  $mail->SMTPAuth = true;      // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'myaddress@gmail.com';    // SMTP username
$mail->Password = 'secret';  // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';  ` this is the key fragment. Is there something wrong here? I get the same error on localhost with XAMPP as on the server.

Comment: Got it working fairly quickly with changing to                                      
`$mail -> Host = 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com';  
$mail->Port='465';` and `$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';`. People. You saved my life. I can't wait until monday to tell the hosting company how useless they are!

Comment: You should be aware that gmail smtp server is good for only 400 out going emails a day. There are other smtp servers which are unlimited IE http://www.serversmtp.com/ or you could use the smtp server from a better host provider.

Answer (score 2):

PHPmailer now on github https://github.com/Synchro/PHPMailer it is used by many apps that need to be installed on systems but don't have the email libs installed. It makes a connection using tcp/ip sockets and takes care of the low level protocols for you.

Answer (score 1):

It seems there is a problem in your mailer server. So instead of researching too much. why should not jump on using gmail smtp, as your application is in development mode you can use gmail smtp for now without stopping your work.

http://lifehacker.com/111166/how-to-use-gmail-as-your-smtp-server

I prefer to do so :)