# Specific steps needed to send email from contact form on a hosted website (not local host) (don't have access to php.ini file)

Tags: php

I have no access to the php.ini file on my server, but have access to the .htaccess file, so how can i set my smtp and send an email from the contact us form to my personal e-mail of the website

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Send email regardless php.ini settings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23443779/send-email-regardless-php-ini-settings)